# Why can't I "import random.shuffle"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

I can do

```
import random
a = [1, 2, 3]
random.shuffle(a)
```

or

```
from random import shuffle
a = [1, 2, 3]
shuffle(a)
```

But I can't

```
import random.shuffle
a = [1, 2, 3]
random.shuffle(a)
```

which will make the interpreter complain

> 'random' is not a package.

Why is this?

Comment: `import a.b` imports the b module or package from a. Since `shuffle` isn’t a package, it can’t import it.

Comment: You can import packages and modules only this way and "'random' is not a package."

Comment: Read more about packages [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: Why writing the answer as comment? Go for it and get some points

Comment: because it's probably a duplicate, or considered as a typo / read-the-doc question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting the comments into an answer.
import a.b imports the b module or package from a. Since shuffle isn’t a package, it can’t import it.
Read more about packages [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Answer (score 2):

You can't `import random.shuffle`, because it's function, so error saying it's not a package is correct.

If you want to import shuffle only, you can do this:

```
from random import shuffle

a = [1, 2, 3]
shuffle(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

Import shuffle like this

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
```